# Scrapy help Indeed scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm sorry if this is very stupid but I'm having issues making my scraper work and I can't figure out where.

The individual xpath items work but as a whole the spider doesn't yield any results.

Would someone be able to look at this and let me know what I'm missing? I'm a complete beginner so I apologize if this is silly.

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import IndeedItem

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobs"
    start_urls = [
            'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=remote&l=United+States',
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = project111Item()

        #all_rows = response.xpath('.//*[@data-tn-component="organicJob"]')

        for response in response.xpath('.//*[@data-tn-component="organicJob"]'):
            item = project111Item()
            item['job_title'] = response.xpath('.//a[@data-tn-element="jobTitle"]/@title[1]').extract(),
            item['company'] = response.xpath(".//span[@class='company']//a/text()").extract(),
            item['salary'] = response.xpath(".//span[@class='company']//a/text()").extract(),
            item['location'] = response.xpath('.//span[@class="location accessible-contrast-color-location"]/text()').extract(),
            item['link'] = response.xpath(".//h2[@class='title']//a/@href").extract()
            #if link:
                #item['link'] = 'https://www.indeed.com' + link
            yield item
        # follow pagination link
        next_page_url = response.css('#resultsCol > nav > div > ul > li > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is your naming in the for loop. Try changing `for response in response.xpath(...)` to something else. The following might work:

```py
  def parse(self, response):
        for job in response.xpath('.//*[@data-tn-component="organicJob"]'):
            item = IndeedItem()
            item['job_title'] = job.xpath('.//a[@data-tn-element="jobTitle"]/@title[1]').extract(),
            item['company'] = job.xpath(".//span[@class='company']//a/text()").extract(),
            item['salary'] = job.xpath(".//span[@class='company']//a/text()").extract(),
            item['location'] = job.xpath('.//span[@class="location accessible-contrast-color-location"]/text()').extract(),
            item['link'] = job.xpath(".//h2[@class='title']//a/@href").extract()
            yield item
        next_page_url = response.css('#resultsCol > nav > div > ul > li > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: `yield response.follow(next_page_url)` is less typing :-)

Comment: True, but doesn't work in older versions of Scrapy. ;) Don't remember, when they added that in, but that's the reason I didn't change it in the answer.